# Evaluate each element in a computed comma separated list

Tags: foreach, latex3, comma-separated-list

I have a permutated list which I sort, which I then use as shades for some TikZ figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3, tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_my_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\sorted}{m}
{
  \clist_set:Nx \l_my_clist {#1}
  \clist_sort:Nn \l_my_clist
  { \int_compare:nTF { ##1 > ##2 } { \sort_return_swapped: } { \sort_return_same: } }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_my_clist
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\myperm}{1,8,15,4,6,5,12,10,13,2,11,14,7,16,3,9}
\newcommand{\mysorted}{\sorted{\myperm}}
\begin{document}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shade using \x*6] in \myperm{
  \x~\shade\\
}\\

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shade using \x*6] in \mysorted{
  \x~\shade
}

\end{document}
```

The evaluation of the second loop doesn't compile, with the error:

```
\LaTeX3 error: 
                A sequence was misused.
```

I suppose the elements of the sorted list are somehow not integers. How to expand them so?

Comment: `\mysorted` is *not* a comma separated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. There are essentially two problems in your code:

1. Your `\clist_use:Nn \l_my_clist` call is missing
   the `n`-type argument, which should be the separator you want to be used between items. For instance, `\clist_use:Nn \l_my_clist { , }` can be used in order to separate items with a comma.
2. In order for `\foreach \x ... in \mysorted` to work, `\mysorted` has to *expand* to a comma-separated list. However, your `\mysorted` macro expands to `\sorted{\myperm}` and your `\sorted` macro contains several commands that are *not expandable* (`\clist_set:Nx` and `\clist_sort:Nn`). Moreover, your `\sorted` macro is `\protected` because it is defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, therefore it won't expand in expansion-only contexts, which is generally required for this kind of parsing. Therefore, the code can't work this way.

I propose a simple modification: rename your `\mysorted` macro to `\mysort` and give it two arguments. The second argument is interpreted as the only argument of your `\sorted` macro. The first argument is a control sequence token in which `\mysort` stores the result of the sorting operation. Thus, the first-level expansion of the specified control sequence token *will be* a comma-separated list after `\mysort` has completed its work.

(Also, since there is no risk here, we can use the already-defined `\l_tmpa_clist` variable instead of `\l_my_clist`—which should probably have been named `\l__my_clist`, by the way: private variable.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}    % only necessary if LaTeX format older than 2020-10-01
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}  % for a nicer layout

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \mysort { m m }
  {
    \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    \clist_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
      {
        \int_compare:nTF { ##1 > ##2 }
          { \sort_return_swapped: }
          { \sort_return_same: }
      }

    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myperm}{1,8,15,4,6,5,12,10,13,2,11,14,7,16,3,9}
% The first argument specifies where to store the result.
\mysort{\mysorted}{\myperm}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shade using \x*6] in \myperm {
  \x~\shade\par
}%
\columnbreak

\bigskip
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shade using \x*6] in \mysorted {
  \x~\shade\par
}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As mentioned in the comments and shown below, one can also do this:

- using a `seq` variable instead of a `clist`;
- using `\int_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}` instead of `\int_compare:nTF { ##1 > ##2 }` for the sorting operation (this should make the sorting faster).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}    % only necessary if LaTeX format older than 2020-10-01
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}  % for a nicer layout

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn { Nx }

\NewDocumentCommand \mysort { m m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
    \seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}
          { \sort_return_swapped: }
          { \sort_return_same: }
      }

    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myperm}{1,8,15,4,6,5,12,10,13,2,11,14,7,16,3,9}
% The first argument specifies where to store the result.
\mysort{\mysorted}{\myperm}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shade using \x*6] in \myperm {
  \x~\shade\par
}%
\columnbreak

\bigskip
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \shade using \x*6] in \mysorted {
  \x~\shade\par
}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this sort of destination-passing-style commonplace in Latex3 programming? I never encountered it (but I must say I am fairly new to it)

Comment: If this is what you mean, it is common in (La)TeX programming to do something using “non-expandable” operations (typically, assignments), store the result in a macro and then use this macro in a place where only expansion can take place. This is exactly what we are doing here. Many `zref` operations work this way, as well as `\pgfmathmarse` (non-expandable which stores the result in `\pgfmathresult`), etc. Many `expl3` functions that “set” a “variable” to something take the corresponding control sequence token as their first arg (`\tl_set:Nn`, `\seq_set_from_clist:NN` and many others), ...

Comment: ... which is why I used this convention. Note: you could probably make the code faster at no cost by using `\int_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}` instead of `\int_compare:nTF { ##1 > ##2 }` (this could have a measurable impact with non-trivial amounts of data, since it is used as the inner operation for the sorting here). Also, using a `seq` instead of a `clist` might speed things up, though I'm not sure about this one.

Comment: I've added a variant of the code with these little changes.